# Gnucash: Default reconcile date to today?

Tags: gnucash, reconciling

When I begin reconciling an account in GnuCash, the statement date field is populated with a value that seems to be random. Is there a way to make it default to the current date?

Comment: I don't think it's random; it's usually the same day as the previous reconciliation, but one month later. So if your last reconciliation used a statement date of 2020-02-02, the next one will use 2020-03-02. That said, the same shortcuts work in all date fields: typing `t` sets it to **t**oday.

Comment: @chepner: Great, thanks. If you enter this as an answer, I'll accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tony, there IS a way to make it default to today's date.

If you open *Edit / Preferences*, then select the *Register* tab, you will see a tickbox option for **"Always reconcile to today"**.  The helptext indicates that the result of ticking this box will be *Always open the reconcile dialog using today's date for the statement date, regardless of previous reconciliations*.

I think that is what you are after.

Answer (score 5):

While I don't know of a way to make today's date (rather than what I believe to be one month following the previous reconciled statement's date) the default, you can press `t` in any date field to cause the current day's date to be entered.

Comment: FWIW, the date still seems random. I last reconciled an account on 2/29; the latest date populated was 2/22. Weird.